# Validation failed for one or more entities when I want to save changes in SQL DataBase

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework

I get this error when I try to save changes in database using Entity Framework, this is my code :

```
public void AjoutDatePoint(DateTime date)
{
    int dateStamp = Convert.ToInt32((date - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).ToLocalTime()).TotalSeconds);

    DataModel.TB_TA_RESULT result= new DataModel.TB_TA_RESULT();
    result.nDateTime = dateStamp;
    result.nUserIdn = 1;
    result.nShiftIdn = 3;

    SessionContext.DBContext.TB_TA_RESULT.Add(result);
    SessionContext.Save();
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when EF validates the entity (before posting to the database) to ensure that it respects the configured contract (max length, required value, and so on).

Because you didn't post the entity definition + EF configuration, I can't tell you which property EF is complaining about.

But you can figure it out quite easily yourself by catching the exception, which will be of type DbEntityValidationException, and then examining the contents of the EntityValidationErrors property on the exception.  From it you will get very specific information that will tell you which property(ies) need attention and why.

Comment: thank you, the problem has been already solved, and the problem was, as you said, required values in the database table. thank you !